# AS3 InputTextField Component size change

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to use text input component and I drag it on the stage, I give it a instance name. Now from code I'm trying to change the size of it by instance name , because I expand a little bit and the text size remain like it was.
Here is my code:

```
userLog.size = 30;
```

I receive this error: 
1119:Access of possibly undefined property size through a reference with static type fl.controls:TextInput.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
userLog.width = 30;
```

Or even:

```
userLog.width = userLog.textWidth ;
```

Or even more:

```
userLog.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,onChange);

function onChange(e:Event):void{
    var new_width:Number;

    if(userLog.textWidth<100){
        new_width = 100;
    } else {
        new_width = userLog.textWidth;
    }

    userLog.width = new_width;
}
```

**UPDATE.** In case you want to change `TextInput`'s font size , use [`TextFormat`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html):

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.size = 24;
userLog.setStyle("textFormat", format);
```

Comment: thanks for response, but it doesn't work. First line  userLog.width = 30  are changing the entire text field. I like to change only the text size inside of userLog.  Second line make my input text disappear.